# updatepanel postback in content placeholder

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, .net

i have the following code:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
    <script type="text/javascript">

        document.body.onload = function RefreshPanelEveryMinuteLoop() {
            if (document.getElementById('<%=drptime.ClientID %>').value > 0) {
                __doPostBack('UpdatePanel1', '');
                //var SelectedValue = ddlRefreshGrid.options[ddlRefreshGrid.selectedIndex()].value;

                setTimeout(RefreshPanelEveryMinuteLoop, document.getElementById('<%=drptime.ClientID %>').value);

            }
        }


    </script>

        <div class="dropbox">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="drptime" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem Value="60000" Text="1 Minute" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="180000" Text="3 Minute"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="Don't Refresh"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </div>

               <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" OnLoad="UpdatePanel1_Load">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Repeater ID="gvd" runat="server" OnItemCommand="gvd_ItemCommand" OnItemDataBound="gvd_ItemDataBound">
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                      </headertemplate>
                     <ItemTemplate>
                         ....
                         ....//lines of code
                     </ItemTemplate>
                   </asp:Repeater>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>

</asp:Content>
```

now when i call that JavaScript function on windows load then it will continue refresh the page

in that javascript i have give the settimeout method but it is not working...

it is continuously do `_dopostback` but i want to do _dopostback after some minute which i have defined in

so how can i perform this ?

Comment: Use Timer in UpdatePanel to do this

Comment: You need to place setTimeout before you do a postback, because after a postback javascript will start from the beginning. Then it does a postback again and so on. If you place the setTimeout before the postback it will wait the time the user specified, and then do a postback. After that postback then the javascript will wait the time again and to the postback then.

Comment: i had tried that but still that problems occurs...

Comment: done changes this but still it has the same problem....

Comment: @deepak could you please debug your javascript ? var value = document.getElementById('<%=drptime.ClientID %>').Value;
            var timout = setTimeout(RefreshPanelEveryMinuteLoop, value);
Add a breakpoint, and check if value is undefined.

Comment: @DatRid no value is not undefined... but when i set the value 60000    but when i debug at that time it will display only 6 as var timeout..

Comment: and when i put     var timeout = setTimeout(RefreshPanelEveryMinuteLoop, 0); then in debug it shows var timeout=4